# SQL Sub Query is being appended as a string instead of a proper query

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been trying to use `Rails` `find_by_sql` functionality and pass a `Sub Query` as a parameter. The sub query is being appended to the parent query as a string instead of a proper `query`. Below is my SQL.

```
sql =  <<~SQL
    SELECT
      column_1,
      column_2
    FROM (
        ?
      ) AS sample_table
    GROUP BY
      column_1,
      column_2
SQL

somemodel = SomeModel.find_by_sql [sql, someotherquery.to_sql]
```

The `someotherquery.to_sql` is as below

```
SELECT * FROM someothertable WHERE column_1 in ('test') and column_2 in ('new test')
```

This when append to the parent query results in the below SQL which has the subquery as a String instead of a proper query.

```
SELECT
      column_1,
      column_2
    FROM (
        'SELECT * FROM someothertable WHERE column_1 in (''test'') and column_2 in (''new test'')'
      ) AS sample_table
    GROUP BY
      column_1,
      column_2
```

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql this will always be replaced as string only

Comment: @RonakDhoot What ever is inside the find_by_sql is is a string. But, I was trying to replace ? with the subquery.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why don't you use ActiveRecord's query method to generate the query? It is able to handle subqueries pretty well _and_ takes care of proper SQL sanitization.

Comment: @spickermann Translated to Rails query now. I am new to Rails and trying to understand few different ways of execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that, that the syntax:

```rb
sql  = "select * from model where column = ?"
data = Model.find_by_sql [sql, 'some value']
```

was designed to prevent SQL injection. What you are trying to do here is exactly the thing that this syntax is trying to prevent. That is why it doesn't work.

You have to replace the question mark manually in your SQL before you send it to the `find_by_sql` method.

eg during the creation of the SQL string:

```rb
sql =  <<~SQL
    SELECT
      column_1,
      column_2
    FROM (
        #{someotherquery.to_sql}
      ) AS sample_table
    GROUP BY
      column_1,
      column_2
SQL
```

or by doing replace:

```rb
sql.sub!('?', someotherquery.to_sql)
```

Finally, now you can send it to `find_by_sql` to execute the query

```rb
somemodel = SomeModel.find_by_sql(sql)
```